# How can I add more information about a ManyToMany relation using doctrine and symfony?

Tags: symfony

I have 2 Entities, Employee and Task, and they both have a ManyToMany relation.

Using doctrine, the migration command already creates a employee_x_task table, but it only saves the IDs of the two tables to register the relation, but I want to save more information about that relation.

For example, I want to save how much time X employee spent doing X task, and I would like to save that information (more columns) on the relation table.

How can I do this? Or maybe my approach to this problem is wrong?

Answer (score -1):

You need to create new Entity with `ManyToOne` relations to `Employee` and `Task`

- `Employee` need have `OneToMany` relation to `EmployeeTask`
- `Task` need have `OneToMany` relation to `EmployeeTask`